# What is the use of '->' in a def statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looking at the answer given [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143367/finding-duplicate-files-using-md5sum-unix-command)

example:

```
def md5_checksum_table(dir_name: str, suffix: str) -> {bytes: [str]}:
```

This is the first time I see `->` used, and I do not understand what this does. 
I have tried to search in documenation, but failed to find the relevant description of this.

Can anyone explain to me what this is/does ?

Comment: I appreciate that this was a duplicate indeed, however I tried to search with multiple search strings on SO, and it did not reveal the post from 3.5 years ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [type hint](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), used to denote what type the method returns.

Comment: thank you very much